# Display text instead of an image when I click on the image

Tags: css, image

I develop a wordpress site and I'd like to know if I can can display text on an image (instead of the image) when I click on it : please see the images on dropbox, it will be easier.
https://www.dropbox.com/sh/x17ybbfij6bql9y/AACkrijkh9lceXN0bsnhP2Qsa?dl=0

It is possible with CSS only because I don't know Javascript or Jquery.
Or if you know a plugin which alloxs this easily.
Thanks a lot for your help
Nice day

Comment: give some code you already tried.

Comment: I didn't try anything yet... The site has been developped by someone else (echo-conseil.com) and I need to add this feature on "Nos métiers" also. The theme doesn't provide this possibilité so I have to find a plugin or develop it myself but I do'nt know how. I've found this : http://jsfiddle.net/SRw67/